# gcc -g conflicts with -fPIC?

Tags: gcc, g++

Tested under CentOS 5.1 g++ 4.1.2 and 4.6.3 and 4.7.0, they all produce same results.  How do I solve this?  Basically I can't build llvm with Debug build.

```
[hidden]$ cat x.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int main() {
}
[hidden]$ g++ -c -fPIC -g x.cpp 
[hidden]$ objdump -r x.o | grep R_X86_64_32 | head -10
000000000000001c R_X86_64_32       .debug_frame
0000000000000044 R_X86_64_32       .debug_frame
000000000000006c R_X86_64_32       .debug_frame
0000000000000006 R_X86_64_32       .debug_abbrev
000000000000000c R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000414
0000000000000011 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x00000000000007f2
0000000000000015 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x000000000000017b
0000000000000029 R_X86_64_32       .debug_line
000000000000002e R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000422
0000000000000034 R_X86_64_32       .debug_str+0x0000000000000607
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I solve this?

You don't have a problem to solve (you haven't shown any signs of the problem existing).

And no, `-g` and `-fPIC` are *perfectly* compatible and do *not* conflict with each other.

Answer (score 0):

These are not dynamic relocations.  They will be resolved at link time.  This does not break -fPIC.

Remember there are two kinds of linking, static and dynamic.  Static linking is done by the compiler/linker when you compile the final program binary from the object files, and dynamic linking is done by the OS (`ld-linux.so` in the case of linux).

To get a list of dynamic relocations, use `objdump -R`.  It will only work on dynamically linked binaries, however (i.e. not .o files).

Comment: so this is wrong: http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2006-09/msg00142.html.  Then what's the best way to figure out the "relocation R_X86_64_PC32" error while building?  I searched on Google but with no luck.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce that error is by attempting to link objects compiled without -fPIC into a shared library.  In the case of the post you linked it may be a bug, or ther poster may have just gotten files confused - maybe there are two copies of yuv2rgb.o?  This is not uncommon.

Comment: i.e. The person was wrong about how to check for dynamic relocations.  IF you are having problems linking a shared lib only when using -g then this is probably a bug in gcc.